# Joint probability function (3 Cards without replacement)

Tags: probability

I have the following problem:

3 Cards are picked from a deck without replacement. Let $X$ number of hearts and $Y$ number of diamonds. Find the joint probability function.

I know $X$ and $Y$ are both discrete random variables that can take on 0, 1, 2 and 3. Therefore:

$$\mathbb{P}\left(X=i,Y=j\right)=??\qquad\forall i,j\in\left\{ 0,1,2,3\right\} $$

Answer (score 0):

It is a multivariiate hypergemoteric distribution.

You seek the probability for selecting $i$ from $13$ hearts, $j$ from $13$ diamonds, and $3-i-j$ from $26$ other suits when selecting $3$ from $52$ cards.

Comment: $$\mathbb{P}\left(X=i,Y=j\right)=\dfrac{\left(\begin{array}{c}
13\\
i
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
13\\
j
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
26\\
2-i-j
\end{array}\right)}{\left(\begin{array}{c}
52\\
2
\end{array}\right)}\qquad\forall i,j\in\left\{ 0,1,2,3\right\} $$ I'm not sure. It's ok?

Comment: Sorry. Now??$$\mathbb{P}\left(X=i,Y=j\right)=\dfrac{\left(\begin{array}{c} 13\\ i \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} 13\\ j \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} 26\\ 3-i-j \end{array}\right)}{\left(\begin{array}{c} 52\\ 3 \end{array}\right)}\qquad\forall i,j\in\left\{ 0,1,2,3\right\}$$

Comment: That's the one.